# print 2D list of lists in haskell

Tags: haskell

If I have list of lists, and I want to make a table of them, so that they are all aligned, and all columns the same with. I started but don't know how to continue..

```
table xxs
    | length (nub [length xs | xs <- xxs])/=1 = error "not simetric"
    | otherwise = (mapM_ print) [ xs | xs <- xxs]

bignumber xxs = maximum [length (show (maximum xs))| xs<-xxs]
```

Example:

```
table [[1,2,456],[34,2,34]-->

  1   1 456
 34   2  34
```

Comment: The code you showed us is not valid haskell code. your function name can not be `2D`. And what do you define `2D` for if your are not using it? And in your example you have missing parens and the function application is missing.

Comment: Thank you, I renamed the function. The example I gave is how it should look like, so without parens

Comment: the function call should be `table [[1,2,456],[34,2,34]]`, so you are asking how to suppress the output of the parens and comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `printf` for prettyprinting and you could use `transpose` to calculate `maxlen` of columns

```
import Text.Printf
import Data.List (transpose)

table = undefined

showtable xxs = mapM_ (showrow. zip maxlens) xxs
  where
    maxlens = map (show . (+ 1)) $ foldr (max.length.show) 0 $ transpose xxs
    showcell (maxl,c) = printf ("%" ++ ml ++ "s") $ show c
    showrow xs = mapM_ showcell xs >> putStrLn ""
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import Data.List

print_ x =  putStr $ (show x) ++ "\t" 

table xxs 
    | length (nub [length xs | xs <- xxs])/=1 = error "not simetric"
    | otherwise = mapM_ printRow xxs 
        where printRow xs =  (mapM_ print_) xs >> putStrLn ""
```

**Demo:**

```
table [[1,2,456],[34,2,34]]
1   2   456  
34  2   34
```