# Pretty-Printing 2D List in Haskell (Explanation of Failure)

Tags: haskell, io, pretty-print

[Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546523/print-2d-list-of-lists-in-haskell) [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546523/print-2d-list-of-lists-in-haskell) for *how* to pretty-print in Haskell, including how to do it with [packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292868/how-do-i-pretty-print-a-table-in-haskell), but this is more a question about why my first approach failed.

Given a 2D list of the form `w = [r,r1,r2]`, where w,r are of  respective data types `w::W`, `r::R` (simple vars for the example, not my actual naming convention):

```
data X = Y | Z
         deriving (Eq, Show)

data R = [X]
         deriving (Eq, Show)

data W = [R]
         deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Why wouldn't either of the following approaches work? (I'm fully aware this will include the brackets and commas, that's not an issue)

```
ppR :: R -> IO ()
ppR = putStrLn . show
```

and either

```
ppW :: W -> IO W (?)
ppW (w:[]) = ppR w
ppW (w:ws) = ppR w >> ppW ws
```

or

```
ppW :: W -> IO W (?)
ppW (w:[]) = putStrLn . show w
ppW (w:ws) = putStrLn . show w >> ppW ws
```

I don't quite know the types of `ppW`, I'm still learning. In addition to my clearly naive (lack of) understand of Haskell's handling of impure functions, I'm also stymied by the fact that the second approach to ppW typechecks (with no provided type).

Why doesn't this approach work? Can you not recursively print a 2D list of indeterminate length in Haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the type should be `ppW :: W -> IO ()`.  `()` (pronounced "unit") is a type which can have only one* value - namely `()`. So `IO ()` is an IO action which as a result gives no value (It is equivalence of void functions from C, C++ or Java).

Here is some piece of code that should compile:

```
data X = Y | Z
  deriving (Eq, Show)

type R = [X]

type W = [R]

ppR :: R -> IO ()
ppR = putStrLn . show

ppW :: W -> IO ()
ppW (w:[]) = ppR w
ppW (w:ws) = ppR w >> ppW ws
```

If you have any problem with types you can always use ghci to determine type of any function. Or you can simply look at the types of functions you are using:

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO()
(>>) :: IO a -> IO b -> IO b -- this is not exactly what ghci would tell you.
```

Edit:
In the code I included I used `type` instead of `data`. `type` defines a type synonym (it is like C/C++ typedef). It is easier to use them than to use `data` - `data` requires you to write explicitly the name of constructor, so you would have:

```
data R =  R [X]

ppR :: R -> IO ()
ppR (R r)= putStrLn (show r)
```

*actually it can also be also bottom, but that's a different story.

Comment: I think this deserves an explanation of why `type` is used instead of `data`. (`R` and `W` have no constructors)

Comment: It's a relief to know that I actually wasn't too far off. I'll mark this as accepted as soon as I can go home and try it myself.